# Adding arrayList to 2x2 arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I wrote this code to add arraylist to my 2x2 arraylist

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> addressesAndCores = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
addressesAndCores.add((new ArrayList<String>().add(remoteIp.getText())));
addressesAndCores.add((new ArrayList<String>().add(remoteIp2.getText())));
```

However Eclipse gives me the error:

```
The method add(ArrayList<String>) in the type ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> is not applicable for the arguments (boolean)
```

It recommends changing add to addall but when I do so it throws this error:

```
The method addAll(Collection<? extends ArrayList<String>>) in the type ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> is not applicable for the arguments (boolean)
```

And recommends I change it to add...

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I get this a lot too with similar containers within containers, but in NetBeans! In the end I got so fed up of the 'warnings' I removed the types and stuck with generic objects. Works for me.

Comment: @iaindownie This is an error not a warning.

Comment: Why are you complicating yourself, doing everything in single line, which got you into compiler error. You do it step by step, and everything would seem easy.

Comment: Don't forget to look at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) when something isn't working as expected. You could have easily found out that `add()` returns a `boolean` and not the `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `add` method of `ArrayList` does not return the instance (the opposite would be `StringBuilder`'s `append` which does return the instance).

The method `ArrayList.add` will return `true` if the `Collection` has changed after performing `add`.

Therefore you are actually adding `boolean` to `addressesAndCores`.

Instead, you can use:

```
ArrayList<String> toAdd = new ArrayList<String>();
toAdd.add(remoteIp.getText());
addressesAndCores.add(toAdd);
```

More documentation here:

- `ArrayList` [add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29) method
- `Collection` [add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add%28E%29) method
- `StringBuilder` [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Comment: That's it, but add() returns boolean, not void, hence the error "is not applicable for the arguments (boolean)"

Comment: that's not ok... cause addressesAndCores expects `ArrayList` not `List`

Answer (score 0):

what happened,

you created your list,then you are adding to this list your text 
 `new ArrayList<String>().add(remoteIp.getText())` then you are adding to your main list result of this operation instead your list,

and as add() returns `boolean` and your list expecting `ArrayList<String>` you have a type mismatch

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that as several others have pointed out.

I would like to suggest that you create your own builder:

```
public class ExampleBuilder {

    public static ExampleBuilder newTwoDListBuilder() {
        return new ExampleBuilder();
    }
    private final List<List<String>> underlyingList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ExampleBuilder() {
    }

    public ExampleBuilder add(final List<String> strings) {
        underlyingList.add(strings);
        return this;
    }

    public ExampleBuilder add(final String... strings) {
        underlyingList.add(Arrays.asList(strings));
        return this;
    }

    public List<List<String>> build() {
        return new ArrayList<>(underlyingList);
    }
}
```

You can then `import static` it and use it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final List<List<String>> list = newTwoDListBuilder().add("ONE").add("TWO").build();
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Output

```
[[ONE], [TWO]]
```